# Increase regex replace speed

Tags: python

I have a df with 20 million records as string text df['text'] and over 100 regex to run against each record to perform replace.

This is taking too long and unfortunately I cannot use flashtext with regex.

Any advice on how to speed this up?

Below is an example of what I am doing now:

```
a = re.compile(u'\d{11}')
b = re.compile(u'[a-z]{1}\d{3}')
c = re.compile(u'\d{1}-[a-z]{5}-\d{1}')

for rows in df:
    df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(a,'', regex = True )
    df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(b,'', regex = True )
    df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(b,'', regex = True )
```

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop, you never use `rows`.

Comment: It's taking forever because you're updating the entire df 20 million times.

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please add the tag for it.

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/15873043) on how to (and why you shouldn't) iterate over rows in a dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's taking forever because you're updating the entire dataframe 20 million times. There's no need for the loop, the assignment operates on the whole df, not one row at a time.

Also, you can do all the replacements at once by combining the regular expressions using alternatives with pipes.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].src.replace(r'\d{11}|[a-z]\d{3}|\d-[a-z]{5}-\d', '', regex=True)
```

There's no need for `{1}` in the regular expressions. A pattern matches exactly one time unless you quantify it otherwise.